# Service nextjs page inside ready working nodejs/exress app

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I have a nodejs application using express as a framework

example: `localhost:2020`

this app serves many routes

example: `localhost:2020/node-1, localhost:2020/node-2localhost:2020/node-3`

I created a nextjs application for just one page

example: `localhost:3000/nextjs-page`

I want to serve the new nextjs page inside my working node app
to be `localhost:2020/nextjs-page`

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy). Install it and include on app on `localhost:2020`, and then setup the middleware:

```
//localhost:2020 app
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

//...

app.use('/nextjs-page', proxy('http://localhost:3000/nextjs-page'));
```